# Programmatically Eject USB Device while it is in use

Tags: c++, c, windows, mfc

How can i programmatically eject USB Device even if it is in use?

Scenarios:

1. USB device attached to the system.
2. We get WM_DEVICECHANGE message by "RegisterDeviceNotification" through which we can handle events like DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE etc.
3. Now if the device is in use, if we want to eject it from explorer, it prompts as "Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device "This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again."

Question: 1: How can we eject USB without any prompt while it is in use?

Question: 2: How can we get notification when the user press eject from explorer for USB device ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't mechanically eject it. So what does it mean to software-eject it? It means that Windows will prevent any further handles to be created for files or directories. As a result, it's safe to remove the USB stick afterwards

Now what does it mean that the USB stick is in use? That just means there are open handles. It doesn't make a difference whether you prevent any further handles from being created. Removing a USB stick while there's a handle open means that you risk corrupting the content on the USB stick.

Therefore, it's not a matter of *wanting* to ejecting the USB stick while in use. The question simply makes no sense at all.

Note that Windows already tells you what you should in fact do: **Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again.**

Question two similarly does not make a lot of sense either. When disk `F:` is gone, why should you care about the details? After all, if you had reasons to care (e.g. open file), Windows would have blocked that operation.

Comment: I have an application in which i have registered for WM_DEVICECHANGE notification.
I have opened a file from USB drive. now if i Try to eject USB from explorer it shows the prompt.
My question is that Can i get the event that shows the prompt for explorer?
I have to handle that event.

Comment: In addition to above comment:
After USB attachment i get DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL notification, now i have opened a file from USB and then try to eject the USB form explorer. How to close the file(which has opened the handle of USB) to avoid the system prompt "USB is in use........".

Comment: Check the method you used to open the file, its documentation will tell you how to close the handle. `CreateFile()` and `fopen()` use different close methods, for instance.

Comment: I have opened a file in i.e. Hex Editor from USB Drive. I Try to eject USB from Explorer, Now programmatically how to find that "Hex Editor" has opened file and how to close it before the Prompt occurs "USB is in use......"

Comment: Well, close the program you opened. That will close the file too.

Comment: Consider the following Flow: Device Attached ->WM_DEVICECHANGE Arrived ->Device is in use(Opened by any app) ->Try to Eject(Close the file & Successful Eject) ->Default System Prompt(USB Device is in use)..............in this flow normally when we try to eject System prompt occurs. i have to close the file programmatically who has open the USB and eject USB successfully to avoid the System Prompt. Is there any event that does the above required task before the system prompt occurs?